# react-native error check the render method of App

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to run a project [react native Tab View](https://medium.com/@satya164/how-i-built-react-native-tab-view-7adfb2570af6).

I followed the exact code but when I run this I get an error `Check the render method of App`.

I don't think there is any wrong with my code but it gives me an error. I think it might be the `TabViewAnimated` but can't find what is wrong.

Any comments or advise would be really appreciated!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { TabViewAnimated, TabViewPage, TabBarTop } from 'react-native-tab-view';

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    index: 0,
    routes: [
      { key: '1', title: 'First' },
      { key: '2', title: 'Second' },
    ],
  };

  _renderScene = ({ route }) => {
    switch (route.key) {
    case '1':
      return <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#ff4081' }} />;
    case '2':
      return <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#673ab7' }} />;
    default:
      return null;
    }
  };

  _renderPage = (props) => <TabViewPage {...props} renderScene={this._renderScene} />;

  render() {
    return (
      <TabViewAnimated
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        navigationState={this.state.navigation}
        renderScene={this._renderPage}
        renderHeader={this._renderHeader}
        onRequestChangeTab={index => this.setState({ index })}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I had to replace TabViewAnimated to TabView. I guess it was a version issue.